# Translation of "to be fluent (in a language)"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, verbos

The literal translation of "to speak a language fluently" would be *hablar un idioma con fluidez*, but I have heard that means that you speak the language fluidly and smoothly rather than that you have mastered the language itself. What is the best way in Spanish to express that you are "fluent" in a language, in the English sense of having mastered that language and being able to speak/read/write/understand it accurately?

Comment: In English it means "Able to express oneself readily and effortlessly" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluent that is "fluidez". "hablar con fluidez" only refers to the speaking just because you're using the verb "hablar".

Comment: @Juanillo: In the link you gave, see the difference between 1a (mastery of a language) vs. 1b (flowing, polished speech). I'm looking for the translation of 1a as opposed to 1b.

Answer (score 3):

You can say that a person is "elocuente". It means the person communicates a message efficiently by means of the spoken language, which is only possible when a certain level of mastery has been reached:

> John es elocuente en español.
>
> John habla español con elocuencia.

An alternative is the word "dominio" (*mastery*), or just say that the level is (very) advanced:

> John domina el español.
>
> John maneja el español de manera avanzada.
>
> John tiene un nivel muy avanzado de español.

Comment: Maybe "Desenvolverse con soltura" can also do the trick

Comment: It might do the trick, but if I understand @jrdioko correctly, that would be more in the lines of *speaking fluently*, meaning that "you speak the language fluidly and smoothly" rather than "you have mastered the language itself". "Soltura", "fluidez" and "desenvolver" express an attitude (confidence), not a skill (mastery).

Comment: I would add as an example: `John habla español con fluidez`

Comment: @Icarus: jrdioko already clarified this in the question and in a comment. That's the meaning he **does not** want to translate.

Comment: @Janoma Sorry about that. I didn't read past the question's title.

Comment: Elocuencia: Facultad de hablar o escribir de modo eficaz para deleitar, conmover o persuadir. That's entirely different to "fluency" and I would certainly not use "elocuente" with that intended meaning.

Comment: Can you use "tener fluidez" and does that change the meaning more to mastery of the language instead of a flowing manner of speaking?  For example, "John tiene fluidez en el idioma."  This is the phrase one of my college profs suggested.

Comment: I disagree with "elocuencia". Most people I can think of right now are not really "elocuentes" in Spanish (or any other language, for that matter) even though they are native, fluent speakers.

Comment: @JuanPabloCalifano that's because most people are actually **not** *elocuentes*, even native, fluent speakers. *Elocuencia* is a state of mastery that not everybody achieves.

Comment: @Janoma. Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Speaking fluently would then be "hablar con soltura", "de corrido", etc, but not necessarily eloquently.

Comment: @JuanPabloCalifano but the question is about mastery, not just fluidity, so *elocuente* is correct.

Comment: @Janoma. I don't mean to be argumentative, but I disagree. As I understand it, the question asks for a way to translate the ability to speak fluently. I don't think  "elocuencia" fits that definition. Hence my comment. I don't think mastering a language necessarily means being eloquent, either. To me, "elocuencia" is related to the ability to tell something in an engaging way, to put it in simple words (and I guess it could even be argued that someone could be "elocuente" without fully mastering a language - though generally I'd say that "elocuencia" implies mastery of a given language).

Comment: i'd never use 'elocuente en español` it means he can convince you... don´t use that

Answer (score 3):

`Dominar` or `domino` works really well. When I was living in the Dominican Republic that's the word they used.